# Hide and Show div works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made such a simple code to show and hide div but i don't know why it works only once. When i show and hide other div, then when iw ant to do it again it dosen't work. Here is code (content of div is not important). In css i set display:none on both of divs

```js
function pokazMail(ID) {
    if (document.getElementById(ID).style.display != 'none') {
        if (document.getElementById('wizyta').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('wizyta').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(ID).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ID).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}

function pokazWizyta(ID) {
    if (document.getElementById(ID).style.display != 'none') {
        if (document.getElementById('mail').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('mail').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(ID).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ID).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#mail{display:none;}
#wizyta{display:none;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazMail('mail');">First.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazWizyta('wizyta');">Second.</a>
<div id="mail">dsjdhs </div>
<div id="wizyta">12313213</div>
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcbm8m8m/

Comment: jsfiddle that beast !

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Lcbm8m8m/

Comment: Ok i will try jQuery, didn't think of that :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
function pokazMail(IDtoShow,IDtoHide) {
document.getElementById(IDtoShow).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(IDtoHide).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#mail{display:none;}
#wizyta{display:none;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazMail('mail','wizyta');">First.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazMail('wizyta','mail');">Second.</a>
<div id="mail">dsjdhs </div>
<div id="wizyta">12313213</div>
```

Comment: this is js, fast efficient and simple. plus one for you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery methods like `.hide()` and `.show()`

Here is and example of using it:

```
function pokazMail(ID) {
    $("#mail").show();
    $("#wizyta").hide();
}

function pokazWizyta(ID) {
    $("#mail").hide();
    $("#wizyta").show();
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcbm8m8m/6/)

```js
function pokazMail(ID) {
    $("#mail").show();
    $("#wizyta").hide();
}

function pokazWizyta(ID) {
    $("#mail").hide();
    $("#wizyta").show();
}
```

```css
#mail{display:none;}
#wizyta{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazMail('mail');">First.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazWizyta('wizyta');">Second.</a>
<div id="mail">dsjdhs </div>
<div id="wizyta">12313213</div>
```

Comment: Or just use .toggle :)

Comment: I don't really think that he is looking for .toggle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use Jquery since I see you using bootstrap classes. Using your approach checking if the display is block then hiding it:

```
//javascript
function pokazMail(ID) {

    if($("#wizyta").css('display') == "block"){
        $("#wizyta").css("display", "none");
    }
    $("#mail").css("display", "block");
}

function pokazWizyta(ID) {

    if($("#mail").css('display') == "block"){
        $("#mail").css("display", "none");
    }
    $("#wizyta").css("display", "block");
}

//css
#mail{display:none;}
#wizyta{display:none;}

<!--html-->
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazMail('mail');">First.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="pokazWizyta('wizyta');">Second.</a>
<div id="mail">dsjdhs </div>
<div id="wizyta">12313213</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've stated was a little bit off than what your code was trying to achieve... BUT I THINK I've understood what you're actually trying to achieve...

So, if this is what you are trying to achieve than my solution will work just fine:
You expect than when you click on a display control element, other 'similar' associated elements are hidden but the one that's associated to the display control element you've clicked... A bit of a mouthful, right? Sorry, but I am not a native English person :(

So the code, as generic as possible is the one I've set you up with on your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lcbm8m8m/71/

Anyway, just in case someone comes up w/ a better idea and overrides the fiddle, here's the code as well..

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="javascript: hideAllButMe('mail');">First.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="javascript: hideAllButMe('wizyta');">Second.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="javascript: hideAllButMe('third');">Third.</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="javascript: hideAllButMe('fourth');">Fourth.</a>
<div id="mail" class="carouselle hidden">MAIL</div>
<div id="wizyta" class="carouselle hidden">WIZTYA</div>
<div id="third" class="carouselle hidden">THIRD</div>
<div id="fourth" class="carouselle hidden">FOURTH</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{display:none;}
.carouselle{}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function hideAllButMe(show) {    

    // Get all the elements on the page with the 'carouselle' class name.    
    var elementsMarkedForHidingList = document.getElementsByClassName('carouselle');    

    // document.getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList and this turns it into an array
    var nodeArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elementsMarkedForHidingList);

    // we iterate the array and hide all the elements...
    nodeArray.map( function(item) {
        addClass(item, 'hidden');
    });

    // and we show the one referenced by the element we've clicked...
    removeClass(document.getElementById(show), 'hidden');
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  var cls = el.className.match(/\S+/g) || [];  
  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    cls.push(className);
  }
  el.className = cls.join(' ');
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  var cls = el.className.match(/\S+/g) || [];  
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    cls.pop(className);
  }
  el.className = cls.join(' ');    
}

function hasClass(el, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}
```

However, I strongly suggest using a javascript library such as JQuery for DOM manipulation and don't get carried away like myself and write vanilla javascript...